# Infinite loop with Johnzon JSON serialization

Tags: json, apache-tomee, jettison

I'm designing a very simple web app with a REST web service that utilizes JPA to interact with a PostgreSQL database and runs in TomEE. My JPA entities have bidirectional mappings and I want my REST service to consume/produce those JPA entities as XML and JSON.

XML serialization works fine because I'm using the @XmlTransient annotation on one side of each bidirectional mapping in order to prevent an infinite loop during serialization.

Unfortunately, during JSON serialization I enter an infinite loop and a StackOverflowError is generated. I assumed that since TomEE uses Apache CXF that it would also use Jettison and I thought Jettison respected the @XmlTransient annotation.

However, it looks like TomEE is actually using Johnzon and that doesn't seem to respect the @XmlTransient annotation. How can I tell Johnzon to ignore certain fields? Could I somehow use the @JsonbTransient annotation from the JSON-B spec? I'd prefer not to link against Johnzon but I tried that in order to use the @JohnzonIgnore annotation without effect. Am I better off forcing TomEE to use Jettison? Any suggestions?

You can reproduce this bug for yourself because the rest-example that TomEE posted on their web site has the same issue, http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-example/README.html.

Comment: It appears TomEE/Johnzon is configured to use getters for JSON serialization. My temporary workaround has been to remove the getters for fields that generate circular references.

Ideally I'd like to keep the getter, tell TomEE/Johnzon to use the fields directly, and to specify which fields to ignore. More than that I'd like to accomplish this without depending on any specific implementations (like Johnzon), just pure/generic JEE code. Any suggestions towards that goal would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: @JsonbTransient should work.

Answer (score 1):

First you can use @javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbVisibility to switch to fields.

Johnzon also supports cyclic references by enabling 'johnzon.deduplicateObjects'.
It basically replaces any cyclic objeccts with JsonPointers and automatically back on deserialisation.
A detailed description can be found in the JavaDocs
https://github.com/apache/johnzon/blob/master/johnzon-mapper/src/main/java/org/apache/johnzon/mapper/MapperBuilder.java#L486